# Borrar todo el texto siguiente a un caracter X

Tags: javascript

tengo una consulta. Necesito **eliminar** todo el texto que le sigue un **signo que yo determine**, en este caso la **barra**. La cadena de caracteres la obtengo de un campo de texto y la almaceno en una variable.

**Ejemplo:**

*www.mipagina.com/publicaciones/favoritos*

Necesito eliminar todo lo que le sigue a la primera barra, quedando solamente:

*www.mipagina.com/*

No veo necesario colocar el código que tengo porque no tiene nada de lo que consulto acá, pero para prevenir algo lo coloco.

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    var url = document.getElementById('url').value;

});
```

Tengo en mente un método, y es que de alguna manera se recorra la cadena hasta detectar la primera barra y siga recorriendo hasta el final, y que desde el punto que se detectó la primera barra hasta que terminó la cadena se seleccione de alguna manera y se borre, pero la verdad no tengo idea de como podría realizar ésto. Estuve consultado preguntas similares que han hecho por acá mismo pero o son cosas de **Java** o son algo como **Eliminar texto entre comillas** o **Eliminar texto específico de una cadena**. Nada que me ayudase pues. Espero sus respuesta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el método [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split) para strings:

```js
var url = "www.mipagina.com/publicaciones/favoritos";

var frg = url.split("/");

var result = frg[0];

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Victor, funciona a la perfección. Vi esa función split pero los ejemplos que daban no eran como lo que buscaba. Se puede dar el tema por cerrado.

Comment: esto no funciona si la url comienza con http/s:// .. tener cuidado.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar la función `indexOf` para obtener la posición del carácter especial y después utilizar la función `substring` para obtener el texto hasta dicha posición + 1 (para tener en cuenta el carácter especial).

Ejemplo:

```js
var texto = "www.mipagina.com/publicaciones/favoritos";
var posicionCaracter = texto.indexOf("/");
console.log(texto.substring(0, posicionCaracter + 1));
```